# Неправильный подсчет

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется разметка (числа могут меняться, привел пример):

```
<div class="items-value"> 17</div>
<div class="items-value"> 19</div>
<div class="items-value"> 27</div>
<div class="total-boxes"> </div>
```

Был написал JS код:

```
 var inputs = $('.items-value').text();
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      sum += (+inputs[i]);
    }
    $('.total-boxes').html(sum);
```

Но идет неправильный подсчет. Как сделать правильно? Считает каждую цифру отдельно, а не отдельную строку.

Comment: у отладчика спрашивали?

Comment: Получаю строку 171927, и цикл for складывает каждое число.
Не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы складывал именно число из дива. :[

Comment: брать его содержимое в цикле, а не с первой строке

Comment: Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Вашем примере используется метод `text()`, который получает контент всех элементов (исключая `html`-теги) и склеивает их в строку. Как вариант, можно воспользоваться методом `each()`, чтобы перебрать элементы и суммировать их.

```
 var sum=0;

 $('.items-value').each(function(){
      sum += +this.textContent;
 });
```

Тот же код в современном формате:

```
  let sum = 0;
  $('.items-value').each(() => {
      sum += +this.textContent;
  });
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. :]

Comment: @Nrks, всегда пожалуйста

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, в принципе да